# mysql join query ID IN

Tags: mysql, join

Table-A

```
========================
ID        |orderIdAll  |
----------|------------|
1025      |299,300,301 |
```

Table-B

```
======================
ID       |orderNumber|
---------|-----------|
299      |200015     |
300      |200016     |
301      |200017     |

SELECT `A`.`id`, `A`.`chalan_no`, `A`.`orderIdAll`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(B.orderNumber SEPARATOR '|')AS order_number_A 

FROM `Table-A` AS `A` 

LEFT JOIN `Table-B` AS `B` ON `B`.`id` IN (A.orderIdAll) 

WHERE `A`.`id` = 1025 GROUP BY `A`.`id`
```

Comment: What's your question ?? ..   the IN operator don't wrok properly??

Answer (score 0):

You should not use comma separated  value for stor  relation key between tables you should us a normalization table

Table-A

```
========================
ID        |orderIdAll  |
----------|------------|
1025      |299,300,301 |
```

Table-B

```
======================
ID       |orderNumber|
---------|-----------|
299      |200015     |
300      |200016     |
301      |200017     |
```

Table-C

```
ID      IDA     IDB
======================
1       1025    299
2       1025    300
3       1025    301

SELECT A.id
    , A.chalan_no
    , C.IDA
    , C.IDB
    , GROUP_CONCAT(B.orderNumber SEPARATOR '|')AS order_number_A 
FROM `Table-A` A 
INNER JOIN  `Table-C`  C ON c.IDA = A.ID
INNER JOIN `Table-B` AS B ON B.ID =  C.IDB
WHERE A.id = 1025 
GROUP BY A.id
```

or if you could work server side a nd bild the sqkcode dinamilcally adding the content  of the column orderIdAll as a strin concatenated  to the rest of the sql code string
eg:

```
s_orderIdAll = "299,300,301";

s= "SELECT A.id
    , A.chalan_no
    , A.orderIdAll
    , GROUP_CONCAT(B.orderNumber SEPARATOR '|')AS order_number_A 
FROM `Table-A` A 
LEFT JOIN `Table-B` AS B ON B.id IN(" +  s_orderIdAll + ")
WHERE A.id = 1025 
GROUP BY A.id";
```

(Assuming that in your server side language + is the string concatenator operator )

Comment: i am afraid,  if I store json_encode data like [299,300,301]

Comment: Your  comment is not clear  ..  try expalin better